# marker causes rviz to be slower with time

Tags: ros, rviz, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Since I have upgraded to hydro in raring, I notice that rviz becomes slower for some marker types. I notice this specifically for CUBE_LIST and SPHERE_LIST. LINE_LIST does not have a problem. I am not sending more data over time. Rviz initially starts with 30fps and then slows down and hangs with time. I do not see any substantial memory leak. When I untick and tick the marker in rviz, the speed returns to 30fps and then slows down again with time.

Following is what I publish:

```
visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
marker.header.frame_id = "/planner_frame";
marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
marker.ns = "path";
marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE_LIST;
marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
marker.scale.x = ROBOT_RADIUS*2.0;
marker.scale.y = ROBOT_RADIUS*2.0;
marker.scale.z = ROBOT_RADIUS*2.0;
geometry_msgs::Point pos;
std_msgs::ColorRGBA color;

for(unsigned int i=0; i<allRobots.size(); i++) {
  pos.x=allRobots[i].pose.position.x; pos.y=allRobots[i].pose.position.y; pos.z=allRobots[i].pose.position.z;
  marker.points.push_back(pos);
  color.a=0.8; color.r=1.0f; color.g=0.0f; color.b=0.0f;
  marker.colors.push_back(color);
}
pRobotMarker.publish(marker);
```

the publisher is declared as:

```
pDeadRobotMarker = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("robot_marker", 1);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84991/marker-causes-rviz-to-be-slower-with-time/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please use the tracking system for bug reports: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0